# py2app does not work with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

if I put "import tkinter" in my Python (3.6) file the mac app I get with py2app does not work.

py2app works just fine with other Python files importing other packages (math, time, random etc) only importing tkinter raises this problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved but I'm not sure it should have to work like this. 
I think the problem is that Mac works with Python 2.7 (system Python) which raises an error when it gets "import tkinter". 
So I installed with Homebrew Python 2.7, redesigned my modules written in P 3.6 ("import Tkinter" etc.) py2app-ed it and everything went fine.